# Поиск определенных обновлений Windows c помощью C#

Tags: c#, windows, update, wmi

Доброе время суток.
Прошу помочь с решением следующей задачи.
Как с помощью c# можно найти определенное обновление в Windows.

Вот мой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] kbName = { "KB4489881", "KB982018" };

        const string query = "SELECT HotFixID FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering";
        var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        var collection = search.Get();

        foreach (var quickfix in collection)
        {
            if (quickfix["HotFixId"].ToString() == kbName.ToString())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("KBxxxx установлено в системе");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("KBxxxx отсутствует в системе");
        }
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);

    }
```

По итогу программа выводи весь список и по нему ищет сравнение по условию. Мне не понятно как сделать чтобы программа проверила весь массив на имя одного обновления и выдала только сообщение которое задано в условии, а не весь список. Понимаю, что в условия у меня скорее всего ересь написана.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: После того как условие выполнится, нужно выйти из цикла с помощью ```break;```

Comment: @alladuh Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для начала ошибки:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //тут массив строк
        string[] kbName = { "KB4489881", "KB982018" };

        const string query = "SELECT HotFixID FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering";
        var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        var collection = search.Get();

        foreach (var quickfix in collection)
        {
            //а тут, зачем-то, вместо сравнения с элементами массива,
            //сравнение с именем класса: kbName.ToString() => System.String[]
            if (quickfix["HotFixId"].ToString() == kbName.ToString())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("KBxxxx установлено в системе");
            }
            else
                //else будет выполняться для всех элементов, которые не прошли по условию.
                //с учетом комментария выше - для всех.
                Console.WriteLine("KBxxxx отсутствует в системе");
        }
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Как исправить? Ну например так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HashSet<string> kbNames = new HashSet<string>{"KB4100347", "KB982018"};

    const string query = "SELECT HotFixID FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering";
    var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    var collection = search.Get();

    foreach (var quickfix in collection)
    {
        if(kbNames.Contains(quickfix["HotFixId"].ToString()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{quickfix["HotFixId"].ToString()} установлено в системе");
            kbNames.Remove(quickfix["HotFixId"].ToString());
        }
        if(!kbNames.Any())
            break;
    }
    foreach (var kb in kbNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{kb} отсутствует в системе");
    }
    Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Или так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] kbNames = {"KB4100347", "KB982018"};

    foreach(var name in kbNames)
    {
        string query = $"SELECT HotFixID FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering WHERE HotFixID = \"{name}\"";
        var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        var collection = search.Get();
        if (collection.Count == 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} отсутствует в системе");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} установлено в системе");
    }
    Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Последний вариант хоть и короче по коду, но работает дольше, пропорционально числу запросов (735 мс против 359 мс при двух запросах), это связано с накладными расходами на создание новых запросов к WMI, каждый из которых в моем случае съедает около 300 мс и рост длительности выполнения от числа обращений к WMI почти линейный с поправкой на погрешность измерений. Таким образом, для одиночной проверки второй вариант, вероятно, будет удобнее, но для проверки по списку - категорически не рекомендую, WMI хоть и мощный, но слишком медленный для такого.

Дополнительные проверки названий найденных обновлений в примере отсутствуют, так что могут быть ошибки в опознавании нужного обновления, если его имя содержит что-то кроме номера.

Comment: Благодарю за подробное разъяснение и указание на мои ошибки. Код поправил, все работает и свою задачу выполняет. Насчет времени выполнения это не так важно для данной задачи, но все равно спасибо за ваш ответ.